# Kotlin override Java setter

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, kotlin

I am implemending a java interface(Command) with this method:

```
void setInputStream(InputStream in);
```

I want to override this with a Kotlin setter:

```
class ProxyCommand : Command {
    lateinit var _inputStream: ChannelPipedInputStream

    var inputStream: InputStream
        get() = this._inputStream
        set(value) { // This should override it.
            this._inputStream = (value as ChannelPipedInputStream)
        }
}
```

But I am getting this error at `set(value)`:

```
Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature (setInputStream(Ljava/io/InputStream;)V): 
public final fun <set-inputStream>(value: InputStream): Unit defined in ...
public abstract fun setInputStream(`in`: InputStream!): Unit defined in ...
```

It says that it is an accidental override, but it is not accidental...

Is what I want possible? Or do I have to just override the `setInputStream` method. I like the kotlin setter more..

Comment: My guess is because Java version is write-only, which not representable as a Kotlin property, which can be read-only or read-write.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes there is only a setter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Or do I have to just override the setInputStream method. I like the kotlin setter more..

tldr: yes

It's not possible for a property setter to override a function of the supertype `Command`. As a workaround, make your property `private` and implement the required interface methods in addition as follows e.g.:

```
class ProxyCommand : Command {
    override fun setInputStream(`in`: InputStream) {
        TODO("not implemented")
    }

    private lateinit var inputStream: ChannelPipedInputStream
}
```